# How to check if exists when using CrudRepository#getOne()

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a `Document` entity. To edit a document you must acquire a `DocumentLock`.

Request API to edit a document looks like below. `edit=true` allows to fetch the record from database with 'FOR UPDATE`.

```
GET /api/document/123?edit=true
```

In Back end side, we do like this (of course over simplified),

```
Document document = documentRepository.getOne(documentId)    //<--- (1)

if(document == null){                                        //<--- (2) This is always false
   //Throw exception
}

DocumentLock dl = DocumentLock.builder()
                  .lockedBy(user)
                  .lockedAt(NOW)
                  .document(document)
                  .build()

documentLockRepository.save(dl);
```

We are using `getOne()` because we do not need to fetch whole document from database, we are just creating a relation with `DocumentLock` object.

Question is, how to ensure the document actually exists? Because `getOne()` will always return the proxy and I do not see any obvious way to check if the record exists in databse.

**Versions:**

- spring-data-jpa: 2.2.6.RELEASE
- hibernate: 5.4.12

**Update**: removed additional questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `findById` or `existsById`. Yes they do access the database. That is the point of it, isn't it?

`getOne` is explicitly for use cases where you already know the entity exists and only need the id wrapped in something that looks like the entity.

Comment: You mean there is no way to check existence using the proxy object returned by `getOne()`

Comment: Correct. Well technically you could access a non id attribute and check if you get a `LazyLoadingException` but that would be pretty ugly.

Answer (score 0):

If your repository returning value or its transactional management is confusing, you should check your repository codes and entity class design even session configurations that used for querying or even your Datastore design because everything looks fine in this code fragment